# why does pug template fails to address a specific field of an object by name?

Tags: javascript, html, input, pug, javascript-objects

this is what my pug file looks like:

```
                input(type='hidden' value=user)
                input(type='hidden' value=user.questionBanned class='questionbanneduser')
                input(type='hidden' value=user.username name='username')
```

i am passing the object user and then reading the value of questionBanned and username, however in the html file this is how it looks:
[image]

as you can clearly see an object is passed into the first input which behaves correctly, and the last input reads the object correctly and its value is correct and the username, however the value of the second input is empty?
it is supposed to say true, since as you see in the object user the field "questionBanned" is true.

what am I doing wrong? is it forbidden to use boolean values or am I rading it wrongly?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the boolean to a string:

```
value = user.questionBanned.toString()
```